# Use parameters in angular factory for custom header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parameters, ionic-framework

I'm trying to find a way to pass a parameter so I can use it in my 'endpoint' variable, as you can see in my code I have the url and in the end of it I have "/clientes", but, in my API I also have "products" and "travels", so I'm looking for a solution to use a variable so I can change the end of the url, otherwise I'll have to create another factories just to get my "products" and my "travels".

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])



    .factory('ServiceClientes', ['$http', function ($http) {


        var endpoint = 'http://api.rep.com/api/clientes';
        var token = '99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2J2J0G9JkD0bDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8';
        var credencial = 'rm@w.com:cd8cdx5ef753a06ee79fc75dc7cfe66c';
        var origem = 'mobile';


        var config = {
            url: endpoint,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: '',
            headers: {
                'X-API-TOKEN': token,
                'X-API-CREDENCIAL': credencial,
                'X-API-ORIGEM': origem,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        };


        return {

            getAll: function () {
                return $http(config);
            }

        };



    }]);
```

controller:

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function ($scope, ServiceClientes) {

        ServiceClientes.getAll().success(function (data) {
            $scope.playlists = data.dados;
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });



    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then make your function injectable with a parameter:

```
var endpoint = 'http://api.rep.com/api/';

var config = {
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: '',
    headers: {
        'X-API-TOKEN': token,
        'X-API-CREDENCIAL': credencial,
        'X-API-ORIGEM': origem,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};    

return {
    getAll: function (url) {
        config.url = endpoint + url;
        return $http(config);
    }
};
```

controller:

```
ServiceClientes.getAll("clientes").success(function (data) {
```